# Is it possible to specify 2 different SSL certificates for a single instance of Kestrel server?

Tags: ssl, https, kestrel-http-server

I know there is a method "UseHttps" in the class "KestrelServerOptions" that accepts a single certificate, but is it possible to specify more than 1 SSL cert in order to be able to work with multiple domains and multiple certificates within a single instance of Kestrel?

Comment: Not sure you can do this. If this is a requirement though, you are probably better off running something like IIS or Nginx as a proxy server in front of your Kestrel app and handling your SSL there instead.

Comment: Any chance you were able to solve? I really want to do this!

Comment: @Ichirichi nope, I didn't solve it

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by setting the ServerCertificateSelector property when calling UseHttps().
The selector is a callback that you implement by yourself and it is provided with a string parameter which indicates what is the DNS host used by the client to communicate with your server. You can treat this parameter and return the relevant certificate.

Taken from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sni-with-servercertificateselector):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5005, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
        {
            var localhostCert = CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(
                "localhost", "My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                allowInvalid: true);
            var exampleCert = CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(
                "example.com", "My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                allowInvalid: true);
            var subExampleCert = CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(
                "sub.example.com", "My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                allowInvalid: true);
            var certs = new Dictionary<string, X509Certificate2>(
                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            {
                ["localhost"] = localhostCert,
                ["example.com"] = exampleCert,
                ["sub.example.com"] = subExampleCert
            };

            httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (connectionContext, name) =>
            {
                if (name is not null && certs.TryGetValue(name, out var cert))
                {
                    return cert;
                }

                return exampleCert;
            };
        });
    });
});
```